# app.get returned undefined in Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using express in my app.js I set something like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('myVar', 'hello');
```

then in my controller I want to get the value. I do

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
console.log(app.get('myVar')) // undefineded
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your controller creates a new, fresh instance of Express. If you want to be able to share variables, you need to pass the instance from `app.js` to your controller:

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('myVar', 'hello');
require('./controller')(app);

// controller.js
module.exports = function(app) {
  console.log(app.get('myVar'));
};
```

**EDIT**: judging by the comments, the issue isn't so much passing `app` around, but moving parts of the application to separate modules. A common setup to enable that would look like this:

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('myVar', 'hello');

app.use('/api', require('./controller/auth'));

// controller/auth.js
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.app.get('myVar'));
  return res.send('hello world');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: wow didn't know that I can pass like that, so if I do so there's no need to require express() again?

Comment: it gave me an error `C:\wamp\www\express\lib\router\index.js:127
  var search = 1 + req.url.indexOf('?');`

Comment: @AmyGlenn I'm guessing that the code you posted isn't the full code?

Comment: the error happends I do this line `require('./controller')(app);`

Comment: @AmyGlenn the example code I posted doesn't involve the router at all, so why it's throwing an error is beyond me.

Comment: `var auth = require('./controllers/auth')(app);` is there any different if I pass it like this?

Comment: @AmyGlenn no, but do you also declare any routes in `./controllers/auth` by any chance? Also, since you're using the return value of the exported function (as variable `auth`), you need to end the controller function with `return ...`).

Comment: The following line is `app.use('/api', auth);` and my controller name is auth.js

Comment: @AmyGlenn ah, that does change things. I'll update my example.

Comment: Really? my other route work fine without using any `return`

Comment: new express app? is `.use` means export?

Comment: @AmyGlenn no, `app.use()` doesn't, but previously I assume that you exported the new Express app instance from the controller.

Comment: just an FYI 
for people who want to read more how *req* holds instance to app
here's the link http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.app

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are instantiating a second `app` that you then try to `get` the value from. You need to `get` from the exact same object:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('foo', 'bar');
app.get('foo');
```

If you are new to express, you can use the [cli generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to scaffold out an application that shows you a sane pattern how to use the same express instance throughout your whole application.

Comment: yeah I know how this work but I have a controller and wish to use 'foo' somewhere else..